# How to extract top populate city from a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a set of tables in a SQL database :

- states={id, name} :

| id | name. |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PACA |
| 2 | Ile de France |

- counties={id, name, state_id},

| id | name | state_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paris. | 2 |
| 2 | Bouches du Rhône | 1 |
| 3 | Var | 1 |

- cities={id, name, population, county_id}

| id | name | population | county_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Paris | 2000000 | 1 |
| 2 | Marseille | 1900000 | 2 |
| 3 | Toulon | 952000 | 2 |
| 4 | Hyères | 52575 | 2 |

And would be able to extract the most populate city by counties, i.e :

| city_name | most_populated | county_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paris. | 2000000. | Paris. |
| Marseille | 1900000. | Bouches. |

Try to execute this query, without success :

```
SELECT c.id cid, c.name, ci.name, 
    (SELECT sci.population FROM counties sc JOIN cities sci
        ON sc.id = sci.county_id
        WHERE sc.id = cid
        ORDER BY sci.population DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS city_most_populated
FROM counties c JOIN cities ci ON c.id = ci.county_id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

The result is not what i expected, and don't know how to acheive this kind of query.

Thx for help

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid and will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, also show us the sample table data (matching your wanted result.) I.e. [mcve].

Comment: Yes... It does...

Comment: MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8?

Comment: @MatBailie server version 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fro MySQL 5.x *(which doesn't have `ROW_NUMBER()`)*, you can move your correlated sub-query in to the `JOIN`.

- Find the most populated city in the correlated sub-query
- Join on only that one city

***Note:*** There is ambiguity as to what you want to happen if two cities are tied for the most populated city in a county.  The query below picks the most populated city, per county, then if there are ties for most populated it picks One of those arbitrarily, based on the `id`.

```
SELECT
  c.id cid,
  c.name,
  ci.name,
  ci.population
FROM
  counties c
JOIN
  cities ci
    ON ci.id = (
      SELECT id
        FROM cities
       WHERE county_id = c.id  -- This is what makes it "correlated", it's similar to joining the query to the counties table
    ORDER BY population DESC, id DESC
       LIMIT 1
    )
```

In this query there are ***two*** references to the `cities` table.  This enables the correlated sub-query to process all cities per county then return one `id`, allowing the join on to the other `cities` reference to be on to exactly one row.  *(Having two references to the same table also requires use of aliases.)*

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=73e93e61f88efee11e02f1e832c8510b

***EDIT:***

I had `ON c.id =` but that was a typo.

- It is now corrected to `ON ci.id =`

Comment: well, i didn't know MySQL accepts subqueries in JOIN clause

Comment: @Jean-LucAubert There was a typo, sorry, now corrected.  I've also included a demo, to show that indeed MySQL 5.7 allows correlated sub-queries in the join predicates.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL 8+ then use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT c.id AS city_name, c.population, cn.name AS county_name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cn.id ORDER BY c.population DESC) rn
    FROM cities c
    INNER JOIN counties cn ON cn.id = c.county_id
)

SELECT city_name, population, county_name
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT cc.*
FROM (SELECT c.id as cid, c.name as country_name, ci.name as city_name,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY ci.population DESC) as seqnum
      FROM counties c JOIN
           cities ci
           ON c.id = ci.county_id
     ) cc
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```